# Embedded jetty application built by gradle always returns a 500 (internal server error) when launched from jar

Tags: java, gradle, embedded-jetty

I'm experiencing an issue that I do not quite get.

I've written the simplest `jetty` `application:HelloWorldJetty` that binds to `port 8080` and always returns `'Hello World'` on `http` requests.

The build is configured using gradle. When I use the gradle support netbeans plugin to debug the application, it works and I get the hello world response.

Now when I build the jar and execute it using `java -jar` `HelloWorldJetty.jar`, it does bind to `port 8080` but all responses have `status 500 - internal server error`.

I've never worked with an embedded server before and it feels like I'm missing something. Been searching around for days.

Here's the main class:

```
package com.helloworldjetty;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler;

/**
 *
 * @author george
 */
public class HelloWorldJetty {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Server server = new Server(8080);
            server.setHandler(new AbstractHandler() {

                @Override
                public void handle(String string, Request rqst, HttpServletRequest hsr, HttpServletResponse hsr1) throws IOException, ServletException {
                    hsr1.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
                    hsr1.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
                    rqst.setHandled(true);
                    hsr1.getWriter().println("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
                }
            });

            server.start();
            server.join();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }
}
```

And here's my gradle build script:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

// NetBeans will automatically add "run" and "debug" tasks relying on the
// "mainClass" property. You may however define the property prior executing
// tasks by passing a "-PmainClass=<QUALIFIED_CLASS_NAME>" argument.
//
// Note however, that you may define your own "run" and "debug" task if you
// prefer. In this case NetBeans will not add these tasks but you may rely on
// your own implementation.
if (!hasProperty('mainClass')) {
    ext.mainClass = 'com.helloworldjetty.HelloWorldJetty'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    // You may define additional repositories, or even remove "mavenCentral()".
    // Read more about repositories here:
    //   http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:repositories
}

dependencies {
    // TODO: Add dependencies here ...
    // You can read more about how to add dependency here:
    //   http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:how_to_declare_your_dependencies
    compile group: 'javax', name: 'javaee-api', version: '7.0'
    compile group: 'commons-beanutils', name: 'commons-beanutils', version: '1.8.3'
    compile group: 'commons-httpclient', name: 'commons-httpclient', version: '3.1'
    compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.velocity', name: 'velocity', version: '1.7'
    compile group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.9'
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.4'
    compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: 'r07'
    compile group: 'commons-lang', name: 'commons-lang', version: '2.5'
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.3.3'
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpmime', version: '4.3.3'
    compile group: 'javax.mail', name: 'javax.mail-api', version: '1.5.4'
    compile group: 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber', name: 'libphonenumber', version: '6.2.2'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'jcl-over-slf4j', version: '1.6.1'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.6.1'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-jdk14', version: '1.6.1'
    compile group: 'commons-fileupload', name: 'commons-fileupload', version: '1.2.2'
    compile group: 'commons-validator', name: 'commons-validator', version: '1.4.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpcore', version: '4.3.2'
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpcore-nio', version: '4.1'
    compile group: 'org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate', name: 'jetty-all', version: '9.3.4.RC0'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.20'
    compile group: 'com.google.code.svenson', name: 'svenson', version: '1.3.8'

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.10'
}

jar {
    from(configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }) {
        exclude "META-INF/*.SF"
        exclude "META-INF/*.DSA"
        exclude "META-INF/*.RSA"
    }

    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'HelloWorldJetty',
                'Implementation-Version': 1.0,
                'Built-By': System.getProperty('user.name'),
                'Built-Date': new Date(),
                'Built-JDK': System.getProperty('java.version'),
                'Main-Class': 'com.helloworldjetty.HelloWorldJetty'
    }
}
```

If anyone could shed some light on this issue I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Is your program producing a stack trace?  Are any exceptions being generated?

Comment: @JJF no errors reported, no stacktrace

Comment: I just ran it & works on my machine.  Used to Maven/Intellij to build and IntelliJ to run.

Comment: @JJF did you create a jar?

Comment: no I just ran the .class file out of target/classes directory

Comment: @JJF, it won't be reproduced that way. Prepare a jar.

Comment: @Opal I don't see how having my .class in a .jar or on disk is going to change the way the this program behaves.  It must be the way OP is running the app.  Something missing on the classpath perhaps?  OP can you post the full command line you used to start your app?

Comment: @JJF it's in the question: java -jar HelloWorldJetty.jar

Comment: @JJF I also don't see the difference. However it does not work from command line.

Comment: I just built a jar and ran it out of that and it worked that way as well. @GeorgeSechu is gradle packaging all of your dependencies into one big .jar file?  I did not build mine that way.   I'm running with a huge command line that references the dependant jars in my local Maven repo.

Comment: @JJF mine's a fatjar. All dependencies included. Might that be the problem?

Comment: @GeorgeSechu perhaps  though I can't come up with a reasonable explanation for why that might be so.

Answer (score 1):

Having a self-executing uber-jar for a Jetty server is possible.

The Jetty Project even maintains a [`embedded-jetty-uber-jar`](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-uber-jar) example project demonstrating this.

They also maintain a [`embedded-jetty-live-war`](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-live-war) example that makes a war file that is also self-executing.

However, these examples both use maven with the uber-jar maven plugin.

> Note: the Jetty project has 2 Apache Maven committers on staff

Now to your gradle build.

- Don't use the `jetty-all` artifact in your build ([that's not what that artifact exists for](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/msg06030.html))

  Use specific artifacts for the features / modules that you need.
- Use a stable/released version of Jetty

  `9.3.0.RC0` is NOT stable, that's an unstable release candidate.

  As of Oct 27, 2015, the current stable Jetty version is [`9.3.5.v20151012`](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.eclipse.jetty%22%20AND%20v%3A%229.3.5.v20151012%22)
- Merge your webapp metadata (if you have any) into your uber-jar
- Merge your `META-INF/services` into your uber-jar