# How to create an executable JAR with tomcat/Jetty out of a deployable WAR

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, gradle, jetty

**TL;DR: ** Looking a gradle alternative for `exec-war-only` goal in `tomcat7-maven-plugin`.

---

I'm having this maven project where it creates a `war overlay` using `maven-war-plugin` and an executable jar is created by `tomcat7-maven-plugin`

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>tomcat-run</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exec-war-only</goal>
                </goals>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <path>/</path>
                    <enableNaming>false</enableNaming>
                    <finalName>cas-${project.version}.jar</finalName>
                    <charset>utf-8</charset>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <warName>cas</warName>
            <webResources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                    <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                </resource>
            </webResources>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

</plugins>

 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
            <artifactId>cas-server-webapp</artifactId>
            <version>${cas.version}</version>
            <type>war</type>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
            <artifactId>cas-server-support-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${cas.version}</version>
        </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

Now Im trying to convert this project into Gradle. I'm able to generate a war overlay using [Gradle WAR Overlay Plugin](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjYmpnhtvLJAhUDxY4KHVNeBOIQFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fscalding%2Fgradle-waroverlay-plugin&usg=AFQjCNGindV_gqc6PWJlFqKb3JBY7aPMpw&bvm=bv.110151844,d.c2E). But I'm stuck with converting this WAR to an executable JAR along with Tomcat/Jetty. In simple an alternate for `exec-war-only` goal in `tomcat7-maven-plugin`. Seems no plugin in gradle offers that functionality so far. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Answered previously at http://stackoverflow.com/a/33378455/775715

Comment: Nope. Its different than what I asked for. I know how to create fat jar. But using an overlay WAR ? Thats where Im stuck.

Comment: That answer has details on making a fat WAR (not a JAR), which is both self-executable and deployable in a container.  The answer also links to the jetty-project maintained example `embedded-jetty-live-war` project that shows you the 4 stages to getting it right.

Comment: Also you'll need to define what *you* mean by "war overlay" as it has different meanings to different people.  (eg: in Jetty terms, a "war overlay" is a 2 stage deployment. deploy war 1, then overlay war 2 on the same context, then start the webapp)